# Apple/Microsoft HIG statements on rebooting

Tags: hig

Some years ago I read a statement in the Apple OS X HIG, that software installers should avoid reboots if possible because they break the system's availability. However, I can't find the source anymore. Could please someone point me there? Is there a similar rule from Microsoft?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with UX

Comment: Questions about Apple's Human Interface Guidelines, and the process of installing sofrware, are certainly to do with UX.

Comment: This question is about the interaction between humans and computers. If - as a part of the installation process - the system requires a reboot, then this takes time and the system behaves unresponsive, which leads to a worse UX. Especially if it is not clear to the user why the system needs a reboot, then this causes anger and frustration = bad UX.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about macOS but the Human Interface Guidelines for iOS certainly do include a recommendation to avoid reboots as part of the [onboarding process](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/app-architecture/onboarding/):

> Don’t encourage rebooting. Restarting takes time and makes your app
>   seem unreliable and hard to use. If your app has memory or other
>   issues that make it difficult to run unless the system has just
>   booted, you need to address those issues.

Microsoft provides similar guidance for [setting-up Windows applications](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/uxguide/exper-setup):

> Avoid restarting Windows. Most programs should install without
>   restarting Windows. The primary reason program installations or
>   updates require a system restart is that some of the files involved
>   are currently being used by a running program. In this case, a better
>   alternative is to make users aware of the situation, allow users to
>   close these programs, and retry the action.

Answer (score 0):

There's a similar suggestion (rule) within the iOS HIG and educational materials to developers, from Apple. It's express meaning is slightly different from what you're getting at.

> Apps that recommend that users restart their iOS device prior to
>   installation or launch may be rejected

from **[this page](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/2016-06-13/)**

The overtone I suggest is being expressed... it's not necessary, in an ideal world, and Apple's ecosystem and products are the ideal world.